# Не скрывается фрагмент в Android

Tags: android, android-fragment

В общем, сам фрагмент создается на экране без проблем, но не скрывается, ниже привожу код. Идея какая, чтобы при нечетном нажатии на картинку фрагмент появлялся, а при четном скрывался

```
                val fragment = PrinterFragment()

                // Get the support fragment manager instance
                val manager = supportFragmentManager

                // Begin the fragment transition using support fragment manager
                val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()



            if(menuFlag == false) {
                // Replace the fragment on container

                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                transaction.addToBackStack(null)
                menuFlag = true


            }else if(menuFlag == true){

                transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out)
                transaction.hide(fragment)
                menuFlag = false
            }



                // Finishing the transition
                transaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы вызываете методы `Builder`-а транзакции, а не меняете имеющуюся. Т.е. в переменной `transaction` остаётся всё та же пустая транзакция.

Вам надо переинициализировать переменную. Например так:

```
val fragment = PrinterFragment()

// Get the support fragment manager instance
val manager = supportFragmentManager

// Begin the fragment transition using support fragment manager
var transaction = manager.beginTransaction()

if(menuFlag == false) {
    // Replace the fragment on container
   transaction = transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
      .addToBackStack(null)
    menuFlag = true
}else if(menuFlag == true){
 transaction = transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out)
    .hide(fragment)
    menuFlag = false
}

// Finishing the transition
transaction.commit()
```

Comment: Спасибо, это тоже пригодилось, но проблема была в том, что я каждый раз создавал новые объекты, поэтому сделал их глобальными и еще, сначала для фрагмента делаем add, потом, чтобы убрать hide, потом чтобы снова показать show

Answer (score 0):

В итоге удалось победить покрутив в коде
Делаем эти переменные глобальными

```
internal var menuFlag = false
internal var menuFlag2 = false
val fragment = PrinterFragment()
val manager = supportFragmentManager
```

И изменяем код на

```
 var transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
            if(menuFlag == false) {
                if(menuFlag2 == false) {
                // Replace the fragment on container
                transaction = transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                menuFlag2 = true
                }else{
                    transaction = transaction.show(fragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                }
                menuFlag = true
            }else if(menuFlag == true){
                transaction = transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out)
                        .hide(fragment)
                menuFlag = false
            }
            transaction.commit()
```

Вся проблема была в том, что сначала для фрагмента делаем add, потом, чтобы убрать hide, потом чтобы снова показать show